# Compute a solution for [spreadsheet]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[spreadsheet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) is a meta tag but it has a definition that describes when it would be relevant (spreadsheet software in general and interoperability between spreadsheet programs).  That sounds like specific usage where such a tag makes sense.  However, most of the 276 questions with this tag do not use it in that way.  The predominant usage is as an unnecessary redundant tag when an application-specific tag is also used.

The tag should probably be retained and the question tags cleaned up.